# Using robots.txt to exclude one specific user-agent and allowing all others?

Tags: robots.txt

It sounds like a simple question. Exclude the waybackmachine crawler (`ia_archiver`) and allow all other user agents.

So I setup the robots.txt as follows:

```
User-agent: *

Sitemap: https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml


User-agent: ia_archiver
Disallow: /
```

After half a year I noticed that the visitor count to my site dropped tremendously.

After a while I realized that Google Bot stopped indexing my site.

Confirmed by their [robots.txt verifier](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/robots-testing-tool):

[image: robots.txt checker]

The `Disallow: /` part is picked up by google bot too, not only `ia_archiver` is blocked.

The obvious question is:

What is wrong with this robots.txt?

Is the **order** of the entries the culprit?

Comment: See: https://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

Comment: This does not solve the issue.

Comment: [Google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/robots/create-robots-txt?hl=en) seems to say you did *not* properly set your file to allow their bot though.

Comment: Sure it does. In its examples, it shows that you need at least one `Disallow` for each `User-agent`. It also tells you how to set it up so that google is allowed but other bots are not allowed.

Comment: In your link there is an entry "To allow a single robot", but not the case I described in the question. Please read the question again.

Comment: It's exactly the case you describe.

Comment: I want to allow all bots, but not the Wayback Machine.

Comment: So add an empty `Disallow` to your `User-agent: *`. Again, you need at least one `Disallow` for each `User-agent`.

Comment: Having `User-agent: * Disallow:` followed by `User-agent: ia_archiver Disallow: /` – does this still block the ia_archiver?

Comment: That's what the docs say should happen.

Comment: Oh, you also probably need the `*` entry to be the last `User-agent`. It's not part of the docs, but implementation has been left up to developers so, often, the first match is the one that's obeyed.

Answer (score 2):

The solution:

```
User-agent: ia_archiver
Disallow: /

User-agent: *
Disallow: 

Sitemap: https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml
```

`ia_archiver` must come first.

The empty `Disallow:` allows all other user agents to crawl the site.

Comment: The order of the `User-agent` lines doesn't matter if the crawler is implemented according to the spec.  3.2.1 of the robots.txt standard says that user agents have to first look for `User-agent` lines that match their name, and then fall back to `*`.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have only one `Disallow: /` preceded by two `User-agent` lines, so the `Disallow: /` is being applied to both of user agents lines: the `*` and the `ia_archiver`. You do not need to include `User-agent: *` in order to allow other crawlers, you only need to state which crawlers you want to disallow. Simply remove `User-agent: *` from the robots.txt file.